# How to remove objects in an array that have the same set of values?

Tags: javascript

Given the following array of objects, how would I filter out

- duplicate objects
- objects with same set of properties (ie. I consider `{ source: "A", target: "B", cost: 0 }` and `{ source: "B", target: "A", cost: 3 }` to be duplicates... and I do not care which is kept)

Example Input

```
let input = [
  { source: "A", target: "B", cost: 0 },
  { source: "A", target: "C", cost: 1 },
  { source: "A", target: "B", cost: 2 },
  { source: "B", target: "A", cost: 3 },
  { source: "D", target: "E", cost: 4 },
  { source: "E", target: "B", cost: 5 }
]
```

Desired Output

```
output = [
  { source: "A", target: "B", cost: 0 },
  { source: "A", target: "C", cost: 1 },
  { source: "D", target: "E", cost: 4 },
  { source: "E", target: "B", cost: 5 }
]
```

Comment: have you tried anything?

Comment: Create an empty set. Iterate over the array. Convert all properties of the object to a single unique value (e.g. with concatenation). See if the value is in the set. If yes, continue. If no, add object to result array (and computed value to set).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Combines (`target` and `source`) and (`source` and `target`) as the key of one `Set`.

Then inside one `Array.filter` to check if current item exists in the `Set` first and add the key into the `Set`.

```js
let input = [
  { source: "A", target: "B", cost: 0 },
  { source: "A", target: "C", cost: 1 },
  { source: "A", target: "B", cost: 2 },
  { source: "B", target: "A", cost: 3 },
  { source: "D", target: "E", cost: 4 },
  { source: "E", target: "B", cost: 5 }
]

function filterout(src) {
  let found = new Set()
  return src.filter((item) => {
    let result = found.has(`source:${item.source}, target:${item.target}`)
    found.add(`source:${item.source}, target:${item.target}`)
    found.add(`source:${item.target}, target:${item.source}`)
    return !result
  })
}

console.log(filterout(input))
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a part for studying closures with a [`Set`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set) and an array of the required keys.

```js
let input = [{ source: "A", target: "B", cost: 0 }, { source: "A", target: "C", cost: 1 }, { source: "A", target: "B", cost: 2 }, { source: "B", target: "A", cost: 3 }, { source: "D", target: "E", cost: 4 }, { source: "E", target: "B", cost: 5 }],
    keys = ['source', 'target'],
    unique = input.filter(
        (s => o => (k => !s.has(k) && s.add(k))(keys.map(k => o[k]).join('|')))
        (new Set)
    );

console.log(unique);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```